# How can I mount /var/www to /www using linux mount --bind command?

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, mount

I'm developing a php application and I would like to mount /var/www to /www.
I have ran `chown -hR www-data:www-data /var/www`.

What I want to achieve is to be able to create new files and directories with www-data as the owner and www-data as the group using my local account without issues.

So I have decided to mount /var/www to /www using `sudo mount --bind /var/www /www` so that all local accounts can modify it also files and directories will be created as `www-data:www-data` but i can't get it to work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "can't get it to work"? What doesn't work, the mount or the new file permissions? Are there any error messages?

Comment: The new permissions, I can't create files under any of the directory (/var/www or /www) using my local account. I get permission denied.  Creating files works with sudo but ownership is tied to root. I don't want to always run chown

Comment: How is this problem related to PHP or Apache itself?

Comment: I'm trying to initiate a git repository using php and I keep getting "dubious ownership" error from git because the folder is created by root not www-data

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for here is the `setfacl` command, which sets the default permissions for a specified directory. After you mount the directory, try the following:

```bash
sudo setfacl -d -m u:www-data:rwx /www
```

If you want to change the existing permissions as well, add the `-R` flag:

```bash
sudo setfacl -R -d -m u:www-data:rwx /www
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by taking these steps.

1. Installed the package bindfs `sudo apt install bindfs`
2. Added myself to www-data group `sudo usermod -a -G www-data "$LOGNAME"`
3. Mounted /var/www/shared/user to /home/user/Projects/www-data in /etc/fstab using

`/var/www/shared/user /home/user/Projects/www-data fuse.bindfs create-for-user=www-data,create-for-group=www-data,mirror=@www-data 0 0`

Files created under /home/user/Projects/www-data looks like they are owned by user but are created as `www-data:www-data`

Output from `ls -l /home/user/Projects/www-data`:

```
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 user www-data 4096 Sep 11 08:40 project_1
```

Output from `ls -l /var/www/shared/user`:

```
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 www-data www-data 4096 Sep 11 08:40 project_1
```